# Capture value from latex to python using latex

Tags: python, latex, odoo, tex, mako

I am using `mako` and `latex` in an OpenERP project (using python) and I need to capture the value of `\thepage` in a python variable, which will consequently be used in an SQL query.

Comment: The latest release of [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) allows TeX information to be passed to Python with a `\setpythontexcontext` command.  PythonTeX allows executable Python code to be included in TeX documents.  That may or may not fit with your workflow.  If you can describe what you want to do in a little more detail, that might make it easier for someone to suggest an answer.